# Can a Jekyll plugin / generator be disabled for non-production environment?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I have an custom [generator](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/) written for creating archive pages (per year, month and day) for my `Jekyll` blog. But that generator takes some time, can I disable a generator for non-production environment or maybe from the plugins entry in the config?

**UPDATE:** The plugin is just placed in the `_plugins`folder, it is not delivered / distributed as gem package!

I am looking for a kind of blacklisting of generators (and maybe also filters or other plugins) for development environment to save building time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693637/10655742 `def generate(site)` for Generators. So I can change it in code for my own generators, but what about 3rdParty generators via gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Local Plugins

For switching local plugins, you could use two different folders, and switch between them with a combination of multiple config files overwriting your `plugins_dir`.

You would set the a different value for `plugins_dir` field in the `_config-dev.yml` file which would overwrite your value in `_config.yml` (or the default `_plugins` if unset):

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config-dev.yml
```

This way you can have two folders with your development and production plugins separate. This has a maintenance cost when you use a plugin across both environments.

---

## Gemfile Plugins

For switching gem-based plugins, you could use a different Gemfile for development without the production plugins:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile-dev bundle exec jekyll build
```

This gives you a lot of flexibility at the cost of maintaining two files. You'd want to ensure the versions of plugins across both are the same.

Alternatively, you could use an additional config file for development. You would set the a different value for `plugins` field in the `_config-dev.yml` file which would overwrite your value in `_config.yml`. You'd need to ensure your plugins are not set in the `:jekyll_plugins` group in your `Gemfile` for this to work (as this would shortcut the config setting):

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build --config _config.yml,_config-dev.yml
```

---

## General Performance

If your site has a large number of posts, it's likely that your biggest time saving would be made by processing less of them at development time. You can do this with the `limit_posts` command line option (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options):

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build --limit_posts 5
```

For general build time improvements, I'd highly recommend profiling your site to find the best place to optimise:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build --profile
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test your suggestions. How does `--limit_posts 5` works? Will that limit only show the newest 5 posts or how can I manipulate the scope?

Comment: The plugin is not inside the `Gemfile` near to that area `group :jekyll_plugins do ...` it is just in the _plugins folder. I will update my question as well.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a solution for local plugins. I believe the best thing to do would be to run the same plugins across both environments and improve the general build speed if possible.

Comment: The idea with the different `plugins_dir ` in config.yml sound very good. Here the [docu](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/) to it, I will check if it is working. The two GEMFILES are much more effort